# Snowflake method to get executing Python procedure name

Tags: python, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find the way to set a procedure name variable within a Python procedure.  I know the JavaScript method Object.keys(this)[0].  Is there an equivalent method for Python?